# Generate a random sample with a contaminated log-normal distribution

Tags: matlab, statistics, probability

I would like generate a random sample with a contaminated lognormal distributed  in Matlab.  An example of a contaminated lognormal distributed sample could be bimodal lognormal distribution where you would have 1 large node and 1 small node.

This is what I used to generate 5 samples each containing 10 data points.

```
trueGM=1;
trueGSD=2;
n=10;
m=5;
o = lognrnd(log(trueGM), log(trueGSD),n,m);
```

How can I modify this to get contaminated lognormal distribution?

Comment: If you have a closed form expression for your desired CDF, you can simply generate a uniform distribution in [0,1] and apply the inverse of your CDF.

Comment: Do you want something that is the [mixture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) of two lognormal distributions?

Comment: jonnat: I don't how to code that in Matlab

Comment: Nzbuu:  Yes.  A mixture of two lognormal distribution is OK.

Comment: @Amateur : what do you think of the solution below?

Answer (score 0):

This contaminates a lognormal sample with 25% of another lognormal sample.

```
sampleSize = 10000
pureln = exp(rnorm(n=sampleSize, 3, 4))
contam = runif(n=sampleSize) < .25
other = exp(rnorm(n=sum(contam), 15, 0.01))
mixture = pureln
mixture[contam] = other
hist(log(mixture))
```